# ASP.NET Core Navigation Manager not using `base href` value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly app that is hosted on an internal server on the company network, for example at: https://internal.domain.com/app. The app is accessible externally through a reverse proxy at: https://external.domain.com/app.

In the Blazor/C# code, we are using the .NET Core `NavigationManager` to set up some redirects, paths, etc. which work perfectly when accessed internally. But we are facing a problem when accessed externally since the `NavigationManager`'s URIs values are returned using the internal server address.

We have some code that sets the HTML `<base>` element href value to the external address which the `NavigationManager` should pickup. However, the values returned/expected by the nav manager are still the internal address which causes issues for our paths and redirects. As stated in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager.baseuri?view=aspnetcore-6.0), the `NavigationManager.BaseUri` *typically*:

> ... corresponds to the `href` attribute on the document's `<base>` element.

I cannot find additional information on the above statement or how/if the nav manager's base URI can be initialized.

Does anyone know how the .NET Core `NavigationManager` makes use of the HTML Base element? And how it can be set to use the external address in this scenario?

TIA

**EDIT:**

Below is a sample code for the Login scenario:

- In the `index.html` file includes some JavaScript to setup the `<base>` element and the corresponding external URL. When inspecting the page markup the base href value is set as expected, using the external URL.
- The `App.razor` points to any unauthenticated requests to the `RedirectToLogin.razor` component.
- The latter redirects to an external authentication provider passing the return URL to the provider to navigate to once logged in. The return URL uses `Navigation.Uri` (absolute value similar to `Navigation.BaseUri`). Based on [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager.baseuri?view=aspnetcore-6.0) this should use the base href value but it does not pick up the value set in `index.html` (external URL).
- Navigation fails after the login provider navigates to the internal app URL.

**wwwroot/index.html:**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var appBase = document.createElement('base');
    appBase.href = "/app/";
    
    //not actual if condition, but same logic
    if (window.location.href.startsWith("https://external.domain.com")) {
        appBase.href = "https://external.domain.com/app/";
    }

    document.head.appendChild(appBase);
</script>
</head>
```

**App.razor**

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin />
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

**RedirectToLogin.razor**

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var uri = Navigation.Uri;

        if (!uri.EndsWith("/"))
            uri += "/";

        Navigation.NavigateTo($"authentication/login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(uri)}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder whether you need the base URI at all? Relative links will work regardless of the base URI (which would be different if the base path were different internally vs externally, e.g. `internal.domain.com/project-codename` vs `fancy-app.com/`). So what's your use case for BaseURI?

Comment: @stefan one scenario is that we use some external providers (for authorization, media, etc.) that require us to send an absolute URL. In this case it is sending the internal address which won't work externally.

Comment: We have a similar issue with a proxy running in IIS and it is the proxy which can rewrite addresses from the internal to the external address since the app itself shouldn't be overly concerned with the URL it is being accessed from.

Comment: Please elaborate on this statement "the NavigationManager's URIs values are returned using the internal server address." - how do you come to this conclusion - please give examples in code of what you mean.

Comment: "We have some code that sets the HTML <base> element href value to the external address which the NavigationManager should pickup" - have you confirmed that the client has the correct `<base>` when the page initially loads?

Comment: "the values returned/expected by the nav manager is still the internal address" - how do you come to this conclusion - provide code samples

Comment: @MisterMagoo thank you for your comments. I updated the question to include a sample code for the login scenario with some explanation. I hope this answers the remarks you included here.

Comment: I think your question needs clarity - I now think you are trying to manipulate the baseUri for external redirects - is that right? Why are you not using configuration to set the redirect URL?

Comment: @MisterMagoo The user navigates to https://external.domain.com/app/ but the baseUri has a value of https://internal.domain.com/ so the idea is to have the baseUri reflect the external address, as I'd expect in this case... Not sure what you mean by "using configuration to set the redirect URL"?

Comment: Why not set up two sites, one for each url?  They both run from the same code base with different baseUrls.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine that is incorrect. the idea is to set this only for external access, across the entire web app. but also the URLs are already absolute as returned by the nav manager.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis that's an interesting suggestion for a workaround. not ideal but maybe last resort if I don't find anything else!

Comment: I still don't understand the problem - if you just leave the BaseUri as `/app/` it will use whatever address the end user connects to. Why are you setting it in JS like that?

Comment: @MisterMagoo that is the problem, the navigation manager is NOT picking up the address the user connects to (external URL), instead, it has the internal URL for both BaseUri/Uri properties.

Comment: Did you even try it without the JS in the index page?

Comment: @MisterMagoo yes, of course. That is how we originally found the issue. The JS code was meant to remedy this but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

"Does anyone know how the .NET Core NavigationManager makes use of the HTML Base element?"

The `WebAssemblyHostBuilder` [calls into JS to get the baseUri](https://cs.github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/442a380854c25b85252a743c3ba2e21f08fa6879/src/Components/WebAssembly/WebAssembly/src/Hosting/WebAssemblyHostBuilder.cs#L137), which via a couple of hops [takes the value from `document.baseUri`](https://cs.github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/442a380854c25b85252a743c3ba2e21f08fa6879/src/Components/Web.JS/src/Services/NavigationManager.ts#L19)

Comment: The `document.baseUri` should be the base href value, (as shown in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kqbL0c4f/ ) then why does the nav manager baseUri not reflect this?